# scope_identity returns null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am writing a SP in SQL server

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAddUserBadge]
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.SE_UserBadge
    (    
        [UID],
        BadgeID,
        BadgeAssignmentOrRenewalDate,
        BadgeExpiryDate ,
        AmountPaid, 
        Remarks ,
        AssignedBy          
    )
    VALUES
    (
        17,1, 12-12-2012, 12-12-2013, 0.00, '', ''
    )

    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS id    
END
GO
```

SCOPE_IDENTITY is coming as NULL. where I am wrong?

Comment: Please post the `CREATE TABLE` statement. Does `SE_UserBadge` have a column defined as `IDENTITY`?

Comment: Also missing quotes? `12-12-2013` == `-2013`

Comment: Nope, SE_UserBadge dont have any IDENTITY column

Comment: Well, if there is no IDENTITY column there is nothing for SCOPE_IDENTITY to return to you ...

Comment: So what are you hoping `SCOPE_IDENTITY` will return then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scope_identity will only return a value if there is a identity field, check you have an identity field.

Unfortunately, you cannot alter an existing column to be an identity field using sql. To do this, you have to create a new column using something like ALTER TABLE dbo.SE_UserBadge ADD column name INT IDENTITY(1,1). Then you have to transfer any existing values using IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.SE_UserBadge ON with an update statement. Then you can drop the old column.

Or you can use designer view in SSMS if the table isn't too large.

Comment: Yes, I've just re-read my post and you are correct, I'll amend it now

Comment: this table is having composite primary key and no Identity column, here how can i get the inserted column value?

Comment: There wouldn't be a single value returned because you have more than one column in your primary key. What value do you expect to have returned? Do you have a copy of the table schema? Alternatively you can use output and the inserted table (see bendataclear's answer)

Answer (score 4):

Use the [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) operator to output the inserted values into a table variable then check those.

**Example**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAddUserBadge]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TBL AS TABLE(ID1 INT, ID2 INT)

    INSERT INTO dbo.SE_UserBadge
    (    
        [UID],
        BadgeID,
        BadgeAssignmentOrRenewalDate,
        BadgeExpiryDate ,
        AmountPaid, 
        Remarks ,
        AssignedBy          
    )
    OUTPUT inserted.ID1, inserted.ID2 INTO @TBL
    VALUES
    (
        17,1, 12-12-2012, 12-12-2013, 0.00, '', ''
    )

    SELECT * FROM @TBL  
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

For what I can see, you are supplying a value for your column ID in your insert statement, if you want to get the ID by selecting scope_identity you need to set your ID as identity primary key.

Here this sample when you create your table.

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(20),
    LastName VARCHAR(20),
)
```

Then on your stored procedure, you do not need to supply the ID, this would be generated automatically

```
INSERT INTO Person (Name,LastName) VALUES ('YouName','YourLastName')

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS ID
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: well, have you read my entire post, I am showing him how to create the table if he wants to use scope_identity